# How to reference the ArcGIS Server JS API using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load a JavaScript library from a CDN, an example syntax is shown at https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn:

```
requirejs.config({
    "paths": {
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min"
    }
});
```

How should the ArcGIS Server JS API be referenced? The page at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/ gives the syntax for a standard web page:

```
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
```

but when using RequireJS:

```
requirejs.config({
    'paths': {
      'arcgis': '//js.arcgis.com/3.12/'
    }
});
```

this returns *NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/.js*

**What is the correct syntax for referencing the ArcGIS Server JS API when using RequireJS?**

Comment: Last time I tried this it was a bad idea - ArcGIS JS API includes Dojo, and Dojo provides its own AMD functionality which conflicts with RequireJS. Immediately on load it threw an error. Unless the situation has changed recently you will have to use Dojo's version of `define` and `require`. Generally my experience of having to use Dojo because of the JS API's reliance on it has been bad.

Comment: @tomfumb thanks for the tip. Using Aamir's suggestion below _seems_ to have done the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would do this

```
requirejs.config({
  'paths': {
    'esri': 'http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/esri',
    'dojo': 'http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/dojo',
    'dojox': 'http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/dojox',
    'dijit': 'http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/dijit'
  }
});
```

Then require your modules in AMD style like this

```
requirejs(["esri/dijit/BasemapGallery", 
         "dojo/dom", 
         "dijit/form/Button", 
         "dojox/grid/DataGrid"], 
         function(BasemapGallery, dom, Button, DataGrid){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that when I load **ArcGIS API** to my HTML then I can use `require` like **requireJS** (but with `'.js'` at the end)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
          on iOS devices-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_style.css">
        <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script>
require([
    'dojo/parser',
    'test.js',
    'dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(parser){
    parser.parse();
        ...
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And **test.js** is a javascript file I have on my localhost and it executes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this question is actually about how to load the ArcGIS JS API (`http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/`) itself, not the test.js file